# Angular 2 Inline Style with ngFor

Tags: css, angular

I am trying to have a dynamic height for a div tag like so:

```
<div class="summary"  *ngFor="let chart of chartCounts">
    <div class="bar" [style.height]="{{chart.CSSBarHeight}}">
        <div class="countLabel">{{chart.Count}}</div>
    </div>
    <div class="barlabel">{{chart.DaysLeft}}</div>
</div>
```

I'm not having any luck getting anything to work for doing inline style this way.  It throws an error on the console that says:

```
Potentially unhandled rejection [3] Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected at column 0 in [{{chart.CSSBarHeight}}] in function AppComponent(http) {@150:61 ("ary"  *ngFor="let chart of chartCounts">
                                        <div class="bar" [ERROR ->][style.height]="{{chart.CSSBarHeight}}">
                                            <div class="): function AppComponent(http) {@150:61
```

Anyone have an idea on what I am doing wrong and how to get the style to work in this scenario?  The rest of what I am doing here is working great.  I'd like to be able to set it as a percentage so after it finishes rendering it comes out to something like:

```
<div class="bar" style="height:80%">
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is too much

```
[style.height]="{{chart.CSSBarHeight}}"
```

Use instead either

```
style.height="{{chart.CSSBarHeight}}%"
```

or

```
[style.height]="chart.CSSBarHeight + '%'"
```

but not both at the same time.

Answer (score 6):

With style property binding, we can specify optional units, including `%`. 

(This is documented in the [Template Syntax](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#other-bindings) dev guide.)

```
<div class="bar" [style.height.%]="chart.CSSBarHeight">
```